# Managed File is stuck with a temporary URI, even after saving it as permanent file

Tags: 8, files

I was having this problem: [Files uploaded via custom configuration form are eventually lost](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232379/files-uploaded-via-custom-configuration-form-are-eventually-lost/232382#232382).

So, I used the solution, basically:

```
$file->setPermanent();
$file->save();
```

But then, even thou `$file->isTemporary()` is `FALSE`, the URI and URL seem to indicate that the file is still temporary:

URI: `$file->getFileUri()` yields `temporary://filename.jpg`

URL: `file_create_url($file->getFileUri())` yields `/system/temporary?file=filename.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark file as "used", there is `file.usage` service for that, you can do it by next code: `\Drupal::service('file.usage')->add($file)`, but after removing file from config or changing it by another file don't forget to remove file usage by `\Drupal::service('file.usage')->delete($file)`, otherwise file would not be removed from file system.

In drupal 8.3 default behavior about unused files was changed and by default all unused files should not be deleted, until variable `make_unused_managed_files_temporary` is true.